# Disable Explorer's music style for folders containing mp3 files

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-11, mp3, music, ogg

Windows has this annoying feature that uses different Explorer options for folders containing music files like ogg or mp3. It removes the file size, it make the name column extremely narrow and it adds some colums about the albums or title etc.

Is there a way to disable this behaviour once and for all and make Explorer use the default style everywhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open any music folder. You are seeing something like this. In my example, the audio files are FLACs. But the setting is for all music folders.  It's not specific to the file extension.  I have Explorer in Details view, which I think you must have also.
[image: Default music folder]

Make whatever changes to the columns you want. In this example, I will just add the Size column.  To do that, right click on a blank space in the column header row to show the columns context menu:
[image: Columns context menu]

Select Size on the columns context menu.  You should now see the Size column:
[image: Music folder with size column]

To open the folder options dialog, click the three dots above the column header row and select Options from the menu.
[image: Open Folder Options dialog]

In the folder options dialog, select the View tab and click the Apply to Folders button:
[image: Folder Options - Apply to Folders]

You will get a message box question 'Do you want all folders of this type to match this folder's view settings?'. Answer Yes to that.  Then click OK on the  Folder Options dialog.

And that's it.  To check whether it worked, have a look at another music folder:
[image: Size shown for another music folder]

Comment: Awsome! It worked ;-] Now all folders look the same. I also made the images visible as I guess you didn't have enough rep to be able to do this.

Comment: Great. Thanks for making the pictures visible. That’s right, this is the first time I’ve answered a super user question. I have a tonne of reputation on the sister site stack overflow, which has the same login credentials. But evidently I have to start from scratch here. I suppose they don’t want pranksters posting pictures of Mickey Mouse or worse.

Comment: That's weird as usually when you join a new community with the same base account you start with 100rep if you had some somewhere else.